# Cannot get Broadcom BCM43225 to work on 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

Whatever I try to do, it will not work. The wireless menu tells me it's disabled by hardware switch. It worked by installing package `bcmwl-kernel-source`, but after an apt-get update and a reboot, it stopped working.
Here is the output of `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4357] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H103.00 Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [105b:e021]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
Region 0: Memory at d5400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma
```

I'm using the i686 16.04 LTS version of Ubuntu MATE.

Also, according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers), it is "UNKNOWN" how to make it work on 16.04.

And it does not work on any other distributions I tried either (those would be Arch 2016.07.01, Debian Jessie 8.5, Mageia 5, and GParted LiveCD).

I'm using a TravelMate 8172.

Comment: Remove `bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: @Pilot6 Still doesn't work. Now the output is this: https://ghostbin.com/paste/bm5fn

Comment: Please do not post outputs using crappy sites that do not open. Just post text.

Comment: Please run this terminal command and post the result: `sudo modprobe brcmsmac && dmesg | grep brcm` http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Hmm, I seem to have found a temporary solution. If I `rmmod wl` and `modprobe wl` every time I boot the computer, I am able to switch on wifi.  Of course this is inconvenient, so maybe there's a better way? That command gives no output. I guess because I removed some packages.